# Weka Histogram (Black)

Tags: weka

Any idea why the histogram is in black colour?

[image: Weka Histogram]

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute of your dataset (looks like the [UCI automobile](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Automobile) one) is numeric, not categorical. Only in the latter case will you see a colored in histogram.

Comment: Yes, Its UCI automobile. But if I use the numeric for all dataset, weka doesn't respond.

Comment: Please clarify "weka doesn't respond". Also, this is a regression dataset, so you will need an algorithm that can handle this, like LinearRegression.